# Service Intent must be explicit: Intent

Tags: android

I am trying to make a RemoteService ,I have followed this guide :
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Remote_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example

this is my service declaration in the Manifest:

```
 <service android:name=".RemoteService"
        android:process=":InnolertRemoteProcess"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myService.RemoteService"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and this is how i bind to the service from my client app :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("myService.RemoteService");
bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

i get this Exception :

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=myService.RemoteService }
```

Comment: you have to use a `PackageManager` in order to get explicit `Intent`, for example `PackageManager#resolveService` or `PackageManager#queryIntentServices`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("myService.RemoteService");
i.setPackage("com.your_service_package.name");
boolean ret = bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Log.d(TAG, "initService() bound with " + ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the next line help me:
intent.setPackage("myServicePackageName");

For Example:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.something.REQUEST_SOMETHING");
    intent.setPackage("com.something");
    ctx.startService(intent);
```